# Динамическое выделение памяти

Tags: массивы, память

Нужно объяснить суть динамического выделения памяти, потому что никак не могу понять, что с этим делают и что от этого происходит.
Переписать программу, представленную ниже, используя динамическое выделение памяти.

```
// ConsoleApplication2.cpp: определяет точку входа для консольного приложения.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "conio.h"
#include "locale.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "time.h"

// Функция генерации случайных чисел в диапазоне от range_min до range_max
int rnd(int range_min, int range_max)
{
    return (double)rand() / (RAND_MAX + 1) * (range_max - range_min) + range_min;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));

    int i, min, j, sum, n, a[10][10];
    printf("\n МАССИВ A: \n");
    for (i = 0; i<10; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j<10; j++)
        {
            a[i][j] = rnd(-5, 5);   // диапазон от –5 до 5
            printf("%3d%s", a[i][j], (j == 9) ? "\n" : "  ");
        }
    }
    min = 0;
    //____________________________________________________________________________________________
    for (j = 0; j < 10; j++)
    {
        if (a[0][j] < a[0][j + 1] && a[0][j] < a[0][j - 1] && a[0][j] < a[1][j])
        {
            i = 0;
            printf("\n %d %d", i, j);
            min = min + 1;

        }
    }
    for (j = 0; j < 10; j++)
    {
        if (a[9][j] < a[9][j - 1] && a[9][j] < a[9][j + 1] && a[9][j] < a[8 ][j])
        {
            i = 9;
            printf("\n %d %d", i, j);
            min = min + 1;

        }
    }
    //____________________________________________________________________________________________

    for (i = 1 ; i<9; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        {
            if (a[i][j] < a[i][j - 1] && a[i][j] < a[i][j + 1] && a[i][j] < a[i - 1][j] && a[i][j] < a[i + 1][j])
            {
                printf("\n %d %d", i, j);
                min = min + 1;

            }
        }
    }

    sum = 0;
    for (i = 0; i<10; i++)
    {
        for (j = 1; j<10; j++)
        {
            if (i == j)
            {
                n = 10 - j;
                for (j = i; j < n; j++)
                {
                    sum = sum + abs(a[i][j]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    printf("\n Количество локальных минимумов заданной матрицы равно: %d  ", min);
    printf("\n Сумма модулей элементов выше главной диагонали равна: %d  ", sum);
    _getch();
}
```

Comment: @Ред, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 3):

Если просто переписать, то можно так.

Вместо

```
a[10][10]
```

напишите

```
**a = (int **)malloc(10 * sizeof(int *)) /* делаем массив из 10 указателей на строки матрицы [10][10] с элементами типа int */
```

а затем

```
if (!a)
  exit((perror("malloc"), 1));  // ругаемся, что нет памяти и завершаемся с кодом 1
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)        // делаем 10 строк по 10 элементов типа int в каждой
  if (!(a[i] = (int *)malloc(10 * sizeof(int)))) 
    exit((perror("malloc"), 1));
```

Остальная программа останется неизменной, а в конце (перед `getch()`) освободите память

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  free(a[i]);
free(a);
```

И добавьте

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

в начале программы (для perror() и printf()).

Или же, предполагая, что ConsoleApplication2.cpp означает, что Вы используете C++, можно так

```
int **a = new int *[10];
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  a[i] = new int[10];

.... тут текст программы

for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  delete [] a[i];
delete [] a;
```

Теперь можно уйти от константы 10, заменив ее на какую-либо переменную (например `nn`), значение которой можно получить из параметров командной строки или прочесть с клавиатуры.

Если что-то непонятно, задавайте новые вопросы.

Answer (score 1):

`a[10][10]`

Вы создали массив 10х10. Вы статически при любом поведении вашей программы выделяете массив такой размерности. Динамически - значит выделять столько, сколько нужно в момент выполнения программы. В С++ это оператор new, в С это функции malloc, realloc, calloc.

Answer (score 0):

Читайте на википедии, что такое стек и куча (раздел информатика).

Comment: Вообще когда такого рода вопросы задают, сразу вспоминаю университетсткую книгу, в которой это читал или курс, на котором это проходилось, и понимаю, что не зря потратил время на образование.